# Modern UI - Totals of german currency not showing

Tags: list, calculated-column, view

I want to show the totals of € in my modern SP-lists.

But I do not know how to do it. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you want to use currency column? Or do you want to get the sum of particular column for all list items? Please add some details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Showing Total feature on Modern UI is still not available. Though it is under development as per this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=46102). They started rolling out for some tenants and seems rolled back again due to some issue.

Reference links having same issues

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/2019-Modern-Sharepoint-List-Totals/td-p/357876

You would have to wait till this feature is available, or as alternative use below:

1. Create Modern Page
2. Add List view to it with totals enabled.